# How to prove this result somewhat similar to Du Bois-Reymond's Lemma?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lebesgue-integral, weak-convergence

Let $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be an open bounded connected set with smooth boundary. Suppose also that for each index $i, j = 1, \dots, n$, $f_{ij}$ is a smooth function.

> If for every $v\in C^1(\overline{\Omega})$ there holds
>   $$
> \int_{\partial\Omega} \sum_{i,j=1}^n f_{ij}v \nu^j = 0
> $$
>   where $\nu$ denotes the normal vector then can we conclude that $\sum_{i,j=1}^n f_{ij}\nu^i = 0$ on $\partial\Omega$?

I tried "flatening out the boundary" near a point and the applying Du Bois-Reymond's lemma. But what I get doesn't actually fulfill all the conditions to use Du Bois-Reymond's lemma.

If someone can think of another approach that's worth trying, I appreciate the input!

Comment: Do you use Einstein's summing convention?

Comment: @gerw Yes! Sorry, I should have mentioned that.